# Best way to initiate into SAP HANA

Tags: database, hana

SAP HANA is a database, like Oracle.

In Oracle world one finds lots of Pl/Sql professionals who work only in the backend database development.

However, in SAP HANA world, jobs don't require standalone SAP HANA skills. They are always clubed with BI or ABAP

What is the best way to get initiated in HANA: ABAP-HANA or BI-HANA or any other route?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for career advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is true that many SAP HANA projects are embedded in a broader SAP landscape there are lots of projects that actually do native SAP HANA development.

Depending on your interests knowledge in SAP BW, especially SAP BW on HANA, might be very important as core concepts of the business warehouse need to be understood to build something on top.

ABAP on HANA is certainly also a good way to tap into SAP HANA, especially when the customer/client/company you're working for wants to extend existing ABAP solutions with SAP HANA.

Personally I'd recommend to start off by taking some of the introduction courses for HANA development on opensap.com. The courses are free of charge and provide you - for a little time investment from your side - with a good baseline overview of what's what and how stuff works.

There's plenty of more training material out there, but usually it's assumed that you already know what you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in HANA world, We do not work with ABAP. 
ABAP was and still used in legacy BW and ECC systems. 
Now clearly the direction of SAP is to move eveything to HANA. HANA works of SQL . So we have BW applications now sitting on top of HANA , we also have ECC or ERP systems on HANA now in S4HANA.
All these systems work on both coding in SQL in Native HANA and coding on ABAP for ECC or BI. But clearly the direction is more towards working on SQL with HANA Native objects.

The way to go forward is possibly this depending on your background : 
1. If you are already modelling in Data warehouse in Oracle : Start with basics of BW and quickly move on to BW on HANA or BW4HANA courses. 
2. If you are familiar with ERP applications in Oracle then i would recommmend , get a brief understanding of what and how of HANA DB and then move on to S4HANA. 
3. If you come from the Admin side of Database , then you need to understand In Memory DB concepts in detail, then move to HANA and search for HANA BASIS related material.

For all these above 3 possibilities, a good starter point will be to pick and choose short intro videos from OpenSAP. 
This will give you the very basics of the HANA world, from there on you can search the internet for further resources.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to you learn this topics:
- Column database (Concept);
- In Memory database (Concept);
- SAP HANA on Wikipedia;
- Do an introduction in www.saphantutorials.com;

Identify which lines of HANA you like: (Administration, Development and Modelling) 
- Development includes SQL Script and Web Development (XS Engine)
- Administration is similar to DBA with BASIS tasks
- Modelling includes SQL Script and views concepts

You can take more courses on opensap.com